# Filtrar un COUNT

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta en SQLServer:

```sql
use gdocx;
select distinct nom_lote, nro_caja, count(nro_caja) CARPETAS
from t_carpeta tc inner join t_lote tl on tc.id_lote = tl.id
where NOM_LOTE LIKE '%-P2%' AND NOM_LOTE NOT LIKE '%ELIM%' AND ESTADO IN ('I','C','E') 
group by nom_lote, nro_caja order by CARPETAS
```

Y el resultado es este:

```
nom_lote    |nro_caja |CARPETAS|
------------+---------+--------+
LOTE 47-P2  |CJ0123623|       1|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123611|       1|
LOTE 47-P2  |CJ0123628|       2|
LOTE 47-P2  |CJ0123622|       2|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123615|       2|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123616|       3|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123610|       3|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123608|       3|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123596|       4|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123602|       4|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123597|       4|
LOTE 46-P2  |CJ0123609|       4|
LOTE 45-P2  |CJ0123569|       5|
LOTE 40-P2  |CJ0123424|       5|
LOTE 45-P2  |CJ0123589|       5|
LOTE 37-P2  |CJ0123348|       6|
LOTE 1-P2   |CJ0121807|       6|
LOTE 19-P2  |CJ0122748|       6|
LOTE 7-P2   |CJ0122112|       6|
LOTE 7-P2   |CJ0122143|       6|
------------+---------+--------+
```

Explico un poco, una caja puede contener hasta 6 carpetas pero solo la debo contar cuando las 6 carpetas cumplen alguno de los 3 estados ('I','C','E').

Por favor. Solo necesito que me traiga únicamente la fila cuyo total de carpetas que sea 6 y me excluya los demás valores que no lo sean.
Lo he intentado con HAVING COUNT pero obtengo errores.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si la respuesta resolvió tu pregunta, puedes aceptarla con el check que está al lado izquierdo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agregar un filtro basado en una función de agregado, utilizamos la clausula `HAVING`. También le damos formato al código para que sea más legible.

```
SELECT  nom_lote, 
        nro_caja, 
        COUNT(nro_caja) CARPETAS
FROM        t_carpeta  tc 
INNER JOIN  t_lote     tl ON tc.id_lote = tl.id
WHERE nom_lote LIKE '%-P2%' 
  AND nom_lote NOT LIKE '%ELIM%' 
  AND estado IN ('I','C','E') 
GROUP BY nom_lote, 
         nro_caja 
HAVING COUNT(nro_caja) = 6
ORDER BY CARPETAS;
```

Comment: Excelente, muchísimas gracias, he obtenido los resultados deseados.

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, recuerda aceptarla y eventualmente darle al +1, es la forma "oficial" de decir Gracias! en Stack Overflow en español, además haces que el contenido perdure y pueda ayudar a otros usuarios.